# Synchronous webcalls using angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I am having a json having name,value and initial name.when the user click submit i am checking whether value and initial value is same or different for each element of json. If value and initial value are not same then i am calling service call using Rxjs. If initail value and value is same for all element an error msg should be shown that "Error-Data is not changed".But since angular2 calls are asynchronous i am not able to do that.

My json is like this-

```
this.subscriptionList= [{name:"Chat Integration",value:false,initialValue:false},{name:"Dashboard Functionality",value:false,initialValue:false},
{name:"Quarterly Maintenance Window",value:false,initialValue:false},{name:"Remedy Planned Outages",value:false,initialValue:false},
{name:"Schedule Integration",value:false,initialValue:false}];
```

on click of submit button i am calling this function-

```
    submitData()
    {
      var anyChangeDetected: boolean = false;
      for(var i=0;i<this.subscriptionList.length;i++)
      {
        if(this.subscriptionList[i].value != this.subscriptionList[i].initialValue)
        {
          anyChangeDetected = true;
          this.remedyService.submitSubscription(this.subscribeObject).subscribe(
            data =>{

            },
            err=>{

            },
            ()=>{

            });
        }
      }

      if(anyChangeDetected == false)
      {
          alert("Data is not changed");
      }
    }
```

Now the issue is when i call this function, for web call asynchronous call is happened and the flow directly went to if(anyChangeDetected == false) block and every time i am getting that alert.
How can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good use-case for `forkJoin()`.

First of all create a temporary array with that changed elements:

```
let changed = this.subscriptionList.filter(i => i.value != i.initialValue);
```

If `changed.length` is 0, you can quit here:

```
if (!changed.length) {
   alert("Data is not changed");
   return; // we can stop..
}
```

Then submit them and collect the subscribtions:

```
let subs = changed.map(i => this.remedyService.submitSubscription(i));
```

Now you can use `forkJoin` to get a callback when ALL async calls are done.

```
// DO EVERYTHING BEFORE SUBMITTING RESULTS

Observable.forkJoin(subs).subscribe(
   subResults => {
      // all subscribtions done .. 
      let result1 = subResults[0]; // result of first subscribtion
      let resultx = subResults[x]; // result of x'th subscribtion

      // DO EVERYTHING AFTER ALL SUBMITTED

   });
```

Comment: Thank you mxii, but there are other sets of work i need to do before and after service call for all the elements happens like loading spinner animation...

Comment: Is there any way to do sets of work before and after all service calls happens..to make everything synchronous,to have a good control to program.

Comment: Take a look at my edits, added some comments. There is no way to get it synchronous, cause webcalls are everytime asynchronous! :)